# Is it better to have two separate tables (to have smaller sized tables) or have one big table in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a situation where it's possible for me to either have two separate tables with the primary key consisting of two columns OR a single table with data from both the previous table where primary key is a combination of three columns.

Which option is better for read-intensive database in Cassandra?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cassandra - one big table vs many tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770299/cassandra-one-big-table-vs-many-tables)

Answer (score 2):

From: https://www.datastax.com/blog/2015/02/basic-rules-cassandra-data-modeling

> #### Step 2: Try to create a table where you can satisfy your query by reading (roughly) one partition
>
> In practice, this generally means you will use roughly one table per
> query pattern. If you need to support multiple query patterns, you
> usually need more than one table. To put this another way, each table
> should pre-build the "answer" to a high-level query that you need to
> support. If you need different types of answers, you usually need
> different tables. This is how you optimize for reads. Remember, data
> duplication is okay. Many of your tables may repeat the same data.

See related answer: [Cassandra - one big table vs many tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770299/cassandra-one-big-table-vs-many-tables)

Comment: Both cases satisfy the requirement on reading only one partition. I need to know performance wise as these tables are going to be really large

Answer (score 1):

You can use both the scenario but you need to follow best practices recommended by Datastax or Apache Cassandra. you may refer basic guideline as below:-
http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/data_modeling/index.html or https://www.datastax.com/blog/2015/02/basic-rules-cassandra-data-modeling

But for read intensive application you should many things such as compaction properties, table properties, indexes, partitions etc too. If your tables are going large you should take care above properties specially partitions. Hope, this will help you.